# django redirect after post with post parameters after update

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I was looking for help but couldn't find any suitable solution.
I would like to ask about redirect after POST.

Situation looks as below step by step:

1. Simple search form with POST with parameter called 'find' within form. Search form appears on every site and if i call search on site with devices i'm checking referrer  and i'm doing query for device model fields and results go to  devices.html template. Same situation is when I search within localization site, checking for referrer and querying for model fields of localization model and returning query result in localization.html template.
2. When I try to update device i'm opening new edit device template with url '/edit/device/dev_id' when every field of this model is shown so i can update some fields manually.
3. After commiting changes on edit site device  'post' goes to url  'update/device/dev_id' and changes to device are saved properly.

The problem is how can I redirect after updating device to step number one where are the results of search view for devices?
If i redirect after update ('update/device/dev_id') device to 'request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')' i'm getting 'edit/device/dev_id' url ?

Worth to mention is that method POST for search form sends text search input to action="/search" and then after checking referrer shows results, so there is nothing like 'action="search/find".
I know that in web browser we can do few times previous click to show search results incuding POST parameters but it is not the point.

If you have any ideas how to redirect to search results (method POST, 1 point)  after updating please let me know.

Regards AD

I will try to simplify the question ( too much code to paste ):
Given search  below in template:

```
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="/search" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="find" placeholder="Search">

    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" >Search</button>
  </form>
```

in views.py:

```
def search_dev(request):
   to_find=request.POST.get('find') 
   (..)
   <--query updating_fields in instance considering only 1 search result-->
   redirect ? (to search query with POST )
```

Is it possible to go back to search results  after some changes to instance ( for example  update ) considering only 1 search result ?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. From what I understand you have a search page. From this page you can go to some other page to edit some model instance, which then posts data to another url. Is this correct? If so please update your Question to be clear and concise. Also add some code so that one may understand your problem.

Comment: Sure i will try, but there would be to much code to show i think. Answering your question yes, there  is a post to another url to save instance and after saving instance i would like to redirect to search results and not to edit device site.